# Using attr.asdict() filter with a callable

Tags: python-attrs

I'm trying to create a method on my class which will return only public properties as a dict. I am struggling with the syntax. This is what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
@attr.s
class C:
    x = attr.ib()
    _y = attr.ib()

    def _no_privates(a, _):
       return not a.name.startswith("_")

    def public_properties_to_dict(self):
       return attr.asdict(self, filter=attr.filters.include(_no_privates))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you example, `_no_privates` is not function but a method.

The solution which I consider better would be to move `_no_privates` out of the class into the top scope. It's a function that takes an argument and returns a value based on that argument and nothing else.

If you insist on making `_no_privates` a method, you can write `filter=attr.filters.include(self._no_privates)`.

However the signature of `_not_privates` is wrong in any case. If it's a function, it should *only* take `a`. If it's a method, the first argument is `self`, followed by `a`.